# How to store multiple values in one column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I’m setting up a web app for my business and I have three things I need to keep record of which is the item lot number and the part number, and glue weights.  The lot number and part number is done but I need to have a glue weight table that stores the glue weight for every hour that the item is being produced.

Basically I’m asking how would one store multiple glue weight entries for just one column?

Ex.
Lot number: 12345
Part number: 1234
Glue weights for lot number 1234:
1.07
2.07
1.56
1.45 (etc... for every hour it takes to produce item)

Comment: Exactly what type of sql are you using? MySql? SqlServer? If MySql you could store it as json which supports arrays and objects.

Comment: I am using MySQL.  If you don’t mind could you link me to information regarding this?

Comment: I have added [tag:mysql] tag for you. For info, you can do this by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store multiple values in a column for one row in many ways; but there may be a better solution.

For example, if you made the column able to hold a large string, you could store data as CSV, tab-separated, XML, JSON, etc. However, by storing the data like that, it will be very difficult to examine that data when writing SQL queries. Luckily, the thing which makes databases so powerful is how they can *relate* data together.

In your case, you want to store multiple weights against one combination of lot and part number. This is called a **one-to-many relationship**. You would have a table for the lot and part number, where each row has a unique identifier (this would be the **primary key** of this table).

Another table would store the weights, with one row for each weight for each row in the other table. Each row in the second table references a specific row in the first table by having a column in the second table containing the value in the unique identifier column from the first table (this is called a **foreign key**).

Once you have done this, your data is now **normalised**. You can now use **join**s to combine the data together. And use **aggregates** to find things like the SUM, MIN, MAX, etc.

Comment: Thank you for that information, seems like the best way to go about it.  And MySQL is able to store this much information, correct, or is there another database option to use that’s better for this?  Some weights are entered more than once an hour so there will be over 24 entries a day 365 days a year.

Comment: Yes, it should be fine. If it starts getting *really* big then you might need to consider moving to an enterprise-level platform; but you can cross that bridge when you come to it... Try to avoid any vendor-specific SQL, and it should be easy to migrate to a different vendor later if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough example:

Product Table:

```
id | lot_number | part_number
1  | 12345      | 1234
2  | 56789      | 5567
```

Weight Table

```
id | product_id | weight | date_time
1  | 1          | 1.07   | 2001-01-02 12:25:12
2  | 1          | 2.07   | 2001-01-02 13:25:12
3  | 1          | 1.56   | 2001-01-02 14:25:12
4  | 1          | 1.45   | 2001-01-02 15:25:12
5  | 2          | 1.07   | 2001-01-02 12:25:12
6  | 2          | 2.07   | 2001-01-02 13:25:12
7  | 2          | 1.56   | 2001-01-02 14:25:12
8  | 2          | 1.45   | 2001-01-02 15:25:12
```

From the Weight table, you can now make an SQL query to get all weight measurements per hour.